# How to Optimize CSS Delivery

Tags: css, optimization

I have optimized the below links css code. But it still give message for optimize css delivery.

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans%7CUbuntu+Condensed&ver=3.6
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/themes/radius/style.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-manager/css/xyz_cfm_shortcode_style.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-tooltip/js/tipTip.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-tooltip/wp-tooltip.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/plugins/bft-pro/css/main.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/plugins/weptile-image-slider-widget/css/weptile-image-slider-widget.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/plugins/weptile-image-slider-widget/nivo-slider/nivo-slider.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-socializer/public/css/wp-socializer-buttons-css.css
http://www.sampleurl.com/wp-content/themes/radius/lib/css/960.css
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are requesting 10 files.

Combining these files into one will grant you higher score with PageSpeed and Y!Slow.

Merging your CSS files reduce the number of HTTP requests made by the browser. This is particularly important in old browsers, that were limited to two connections per domain.

This practice aims to reduces the number of round-trip times.

Few useful resources

- [Minimize round-trip times - PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#CombineExternalCSS)
- [Minimize HTTP Requests - Y!Slow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed.  Actually I am using different-2 plugins. Each plugin contains their own css file. each plugins has their code page and they call their own css. Are there any other way to resolve these issue.

Comment: You can try a plugin that will combine those CSS files like http://wordpress.org/plugins/combine-css/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Google Page Insights as your only test, it can be very odd sometimes, even missing things that its own Google Page Speed module is doing.

I like to keep [gtmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) around as a much more honest and thorough test.

According to them, you score 92% on "Minify CSS," and 97% on all other CSS checks.
Learn more at [15 Ways To Reduce Load Time Of WordPress Website](http://dignol.org/15-ways-to-reduce-load-time-of-wordpress-website/)